# Warning message for String only unwraps optionals

Tags: swift

```
let condition = (priceModel?[indexPath.row].changePercentage as! String)
```

Warning Message:

> Forced cast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

How to clear the warning message?

Comment: `changePercentage` is already a String. So if you still want to force unwrap, `.changePercentage as! String` => `.changePercentage!`.

Comment: Consider to declare  `priceModel` as **non-optional** empty array. This avoids those annoying errors.

Comment: Shouldn't this warning in Xcode suggest code change like in answers below?

Comment: You don't need to cast `as! String`, but you need to unwrap it.

Answer (score 2):

it means you need to use

```
(priceModel?[indexPath.row].changePercentage)!
```

when the cast force is for the same type use ! as the type is already String so `!` makes more sense than `as! String`

or

```
let condition = priceModel![indexPath.row].changePercentage
```

assuming `changePercentage` isn't optional

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the `if` statement to avoid forced unwrap.

```
if let condition = priceModel?[indexPath.row].changePercentage as? String {
   // the rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let condition = (priceModel?[indexPath.row].changePercentage)!
```

Although it might be unsafe if it's nil